# AppCenter, React Native iOS App, Build error: NotAuthorized: "Bearer token authorization is required"

Tags: ios, react-native, build, visual-studio-app-center

I'm trying to create a build in AppCenter for my iOS app created with React Native.

The build works perfectly, except for the final distribution step, which throws this error:

```
Task         : App Center distribute
Description  : Distribute app builds to testers and users via Visual Studio App Center
Version      : 3.232.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/app-center-distribute
==============================================================================
##[error]Error: {"error":{"code":"NotAuthorized","message":"Bearer token authorization is required","ref":"N/A"}}
```

As I said, the build works fine, except for that last step, so when I go to `Distribute`>`Releases`, the build is there. And I can distribute it manually.

So in conclusion, the problem is in the automated pipeline failing on that step, but I don't know what's happening, because this used to work 10 days ago.

In the build configuration, in the distribution part I have this:
[image: build configuration]

Any ideas what might be going on?